# Remove WSUS on Server 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012, wsus

I have a corrupt WSUS installation and have uninstalled it. However, when reinstalling, it picks all the same settings backup from the previous installation and runs into the same problems again. What is it I must clean up database wise (and where from) in order to have a completely clean/fresh installation.

Thanks

Comment: Out of interest, what is the problem you're having with the installation? I had some issues with WSUS on 2012.

Comment: The main problem seemed to be the MMC crashing whenever I attempted to configure anything in WSUS - Products and Classfications hang it for 30 minutes and eventually it crashes, with the Update Services service crashing to follow. It's very odd.

Comment: Ah, nothing like the problems I had then! Once you've uninstalled the role, have you checked to make sure that the Windows Internal Database feature has been removed? If it's still there, you can connect to the instance using SQL Server Management Studio - if you see a SUSDB there then try deleting that.

Comment: Thanks, first thing I tried was to simply delete the SUSDB and then clean up the WID with SSMS but same problem, odd one. May just take this to Microsoft!